# Android Update TextView(News feed) from Server

Tags: android, http, push-notification

I am trying to develop as part of my app a sort of news feed for the user.  When the user opens the app there will be a box at the top of the app which includes a greeting and information about the user or other information. This information would be pulled from a server.  I think I just answered my own question.  Would an HTTP Get be the best way to go about this?  So it sends a request then updates the textview or whatever according to the information it recieves from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to get data from the network, but make sure you do this inside of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) so your application doesn't stop responding.